# Apache pdfbox convert tiff to PDF - multi threading or sequential approach?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, pdfbox, executorservice

I'm trying to accomplish the following requirement in spring boot rest project:

Given n number of tiff images, convert those to PDF in the shortest time possible.

**Maximum filesize**: 200 MB

My solution so far:

**Solution 1:** Create n number of threads to render the PDF and save it. 
**Time Taken:** 6 minutes.
**Drawback**: The CPU utilized is a lot, close to 90 - 95%.

**Solution 2:** Perform sequential execution of creating one PDF after another
**Time Taken:** 13 minutes.
**Drawback**: Time taken to render 200 MB worth of tiff images is a lot.

Following is the *solution 2* code to achieve multi threading:

```
    /*
 * Converts a mimetype to a pdf format and saves in the output location 
 */ 
public void PDFConvert(String fileName, String dirName, String mimeType, boolean lastProcessed) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
    Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(fileName, dirName, mimeType, rootDir);
    Future<?> f  = executor.submit(worker);
    futures.add(f);


    // Check if all runnables are done (non-blocking)
    if (lastProcessed) {
        for(Future<?> future : futures)
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        boolean allDone;
        for(Future<?> future : futures){
            allDone &= future.isDone(); // check if future is done
        }
    } 
}



public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private String fileName;
    private String dirName;
    private String mimeType;
    private String rootDir;

    MyRunnable(String fileName, String dirName, String mimeType, String rootDir) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.dirName = dirName;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
        this.rootDir = rootDir;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        String fileToSave = getOutputDir(dirName, rootDir) + fileName.replaceAll(mimeType, DownloadConstants.FILE_EXTENSION);
        boolean status = true;
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        try (SeekableStream seekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(new File(getOutputDir(dirName, rootDir) + fileName))) {
            // Gain seekable access to the file
            ImageDecoder imageDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(mimeType, seekableStream, (TIFFDecodeParam) null);
            for (int i = 0; i < imageDecoder.getNumPages(); i++) {
                RenderedImage renderedImage = imageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
                    doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
                    PDPage page = new PDPage();
                    doc.addPage(page);
                    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page)) {
                        PDImageXObject image = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, convertRenderedImage(renderedImage));
                        contentStream.drawImage(image, 1, 1, 600, 750);
                    } 
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    doc.save(fileToSave);
                    doc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}

    //From a Service class, the following code invokes the threads 

    for (int i=0; i<tiffConvertList.size(); i++) {
           convertToPDF(fileName, dirName, mimeType, lastProcessed) 
   }
```

**Question:** 
1) Should I use the solution 2 and create more CPU in the production? Does this change a better runtime for file conversion?

2) Should I limit the file size and inform this is a bottleneck. Maybe create another rest endpoint for files greater than 50MB?

Any better solution would be appreciated, the rendering time is a critical factor.

Thanks

Comment: 1) Please adjust your title, you're not rendering, you're converting TIF to PDF. 2) You could speed this up if the TIF files are classic b/w files. Use `CCITTFactory.createFromFile()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The CCITTFactory.createFromFile() still takes a lot of time to convert the tiff image. 

The solution finally is to use the iText library which is 5 times faster in creating. The 8.1 MB files were converted in 6 seconds compared to 40 seconds with pdfbox